# Como obtener el fakepath desde Internet Explorer

Tags: javascript, html, entrada

Tengo un problema al implementar una pagina web en el IIS.

Cargo un fichero desde el sitio web, el problema esta cuando lo intento cargar desde internet explorer, ya que si lo cargo de chrome no me pasa...
La diferencia que note, es que cuando lo cargo desde chrome, la previsualizacion de la ruta es C:\fakepath\cfdiXml.xml aunque el archivo no este en el C.
Cuando trato de cargarlo desde internet explorer, me pone la ruta real del archivo  W:\User\Folder\folder2\folder\etc\anotherfolder\cfdiXml.xml

Y me marca un error:

```
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code. 

 Exception Details: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'W:\User\Folder\folder2\folder\etc\anotherfolder\cfdiXml.xml'.

Source Error: 


 An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.
```

Alguna sugerencia de como solucionar este error.

Codigo del input donde cargo el archivo...

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("LeerXML", "CFDI", FormMethod.Post, new { @role = "form", id = "myForm", enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
       {

                                        <div class="form-group">
                                            <label class="col-md-2 control-label">Cargar archivo</label>
                                            <div class="col-md-10">
                                                <input type="file" class="btn btn-default" id="up_file" name="xml" accept=".xml" onchange="comprueba_extension();" required>
                                                <span id="Adjunto" name="Adjunto" class="fileinput-new">No se ha elegido archivo (Maximo 3.5MB)</span>
                                                <p class="help-block">
                                                    Solo se admite el formato XML.
                                                </p>
                                            </div>
                                            <button class="btn btn-info" type="reset"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-remove"></i> Cancelar </button> 
                                            <button class="btn btn-primary" type="submit"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-cloud-upload"></i> Cargar </button>
                                        </div>


       }
```

dejo una imagen de la vista desde chrome e internet explorer
[image: app]

Comment: No queda claro lo que estás intentando hacer y no estás aportando el código que te produce el error, ayúdanos a ayudarte definiendo mejor el escenario

Comment: Listo, el detalle es que creo que el error me lo envía la aplicación por como me muestra la ruta en el internet explorer.. quiero que me muestre o me tome la ruta como en el chrome, con el fakepath

Answer (score 0):

No puedes obtener el fakepath, la seguridad implementada de los navegadores no lo permite. ¿Te imaginas que se pueda ver, toda la ruta del archivo? Sería oro puro para los hackers.

Comment: si te fijas en la imagen del explorer, me manda la ruta completa del archivo... lo que quiero hacer es que me ponga fakepath en ves de la ruta del archivo, pero no lo hace en internet explorer

Comment: Ya sabemos todos, que IE es el peor Browser, por estos tipos de issues. Me topé en su momento con este mismo problema, y todo el foro inglés coincide con lo mismo. Los navegadores actuales ya no te dejan.